# probability question - is this correct?

Tags: probability

In particular periods of the year meteor showers can be observed due to entry
into the Earth's atmosphere of a number of meteors. In August on average one meteor can
be observed every 10 minutes. Assuming that the number of meteors is a Poisson random
variable, what is the probability that in 15 minutes two meteors will be observed?

So $P(X=2) = e^{-1.5}\dfrac{1.5^2}{2} = 0.251$

Is this the correct workings?

Comment: This is exactly 2, i.e. not 2 or more.

Comment: Aren't I looking for exactly 2?

Comment: You have given the answer for exactly two, but you could argue that if there were 3 then you did observe 2. The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.

If you wanted "at least two" then it would be $$P(X \ge 2) = 1- P(X\le 1) = 1 -e^{-1.5}\dfrac{1.5^1}{1!}-e^{-1.5}\dfrac{1.5^0}{0!}  \approx. 0.42.$$